# css code is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want that when I work on any of the navigation button it will be color red,while the others will be the same color..Here I have the jstl tag..thats why it is not working in jsfiddle..where is the problem here?

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("ul li a").click(function() {
    $("nav a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
}
header {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 76px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
a.active {
  color: red;
}
nav {
  float: right;
  padding: 20px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px
}
.current {
  color: red;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  header {
    position: absolute;
  }
  #menu-icon {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  nav ul,
  nav:active ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 5px solid #444;
    right: 20px;
    top: 60px;
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 4px 0 4px 4px;
  }
  nav li {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  nav:hover ul {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="<s:url value='/home'  />" class="current">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="<s:url value='/work' />">work</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="<s:url value='/others' />">Others</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: The problem I think you have is the a element is written wrong I think it should be

Comment: Do you want to use both classes current and active?

Comment: Well you click a link...if the page redirects it is moot you add a class.

Comment: so,how will it work??

Comment: Take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/aexcyxL2/

Comment: Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/nujm5huf/ doesn't really matter though since you are loading a new page, so the added class will disappear anyway once the new page is loaded.

Comment: I already Have done it..I know If I use "#" then it is working..My question was when I use "<s:url value='/home'  />" this vale then it is not working

Comment: @ APAD1 , if I use your code then it is just changing the color..but I am unable to go that pages..

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the link you:

1. Start some JS
2. Modify the DOM of the current page to change the class
3. Finish running the JS
4. Follow the link
5. **Discard the DOM you just modified**
6. Load a new page with a new DOM

If you want to change the classes on the link in the *new* page, you have to do it either:

- Before sending the page to the client (this could be with server side code or hardcoded into static HTML)
- By checking the `location` with JavaScript, finding the matching `href` and then modifying that element.

Comment: In my code If I use href value=# then it is woring..but if I use the href value =<s:url value='/home'  /> then it is not working

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of places that you need to change as a starting point.  First in the html, change current to active

```
<li><a href="..." class="active">Home</a></li>
```

and in JS,

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {   
    $("ul li a").click(function(){
        $("ul li a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/janhtgr0/)

Comment: I already have done it..If I use "#" then it is changing the color..But If I use the value of # like  "<s:url value='/home' />" then it is not working..