# navigation css style is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

yesterday I have posted this ..but no one answers.

I have [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/35d5tmd6/)
this code..I want to color navigation button when it is active..It is working here..but when I put this jsfiddle code to my project it is colored until the page is loading,then it is going to previous color.if I use **#** then it is working..

in my code I have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(e) {   
        $("ul li a").click(function(){
            $("ul li a").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });
    });

</script>
```

and the jsfiddle html and css code..what am I doing wrong?pls guys suggest me.

Comment: You are executing the script and is navigating to  a different page... so any changes done by the first page will be lost when the new page is loaded

Comment: possible duplicate of [css code is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704613/css-code-is-not-working)

Comment: @arun,so how can I achieve my requirement???

Comment: @ JustAnotherDotNetDe, yes this the the ques..but do u know the solution??

Comment: check if you want this http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/977cyu6j/

Comment: @Tribute to APJ Kalam Sir, I already have used this..If I use "e.preventDefault();"  then it just changes the color and it is in the same page,.after click a button it is not fetching the pages..

Comment: @Salini you should then read @ Arun Sir's commment

Comment: @ Tribute to APJ Kalam Sir, yes I have read..But that is not true always..we can manage it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as @Arun has commented on your question. javascript action is only on the DOM elements that you are currently on.

But the solution for you is via [jquery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). You can save your clicked element on jquerycookie and can retrieve on next page. For detail please read the [jquerycookie usage](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#usage)

**Update** : Try this `jQuery('a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').addClass('active');` if your link is `<a href="/blog.php">x</a>`

And try `jQuery('a[href="' + this.location.href + '"]').addClass('active');` if your link is `<a href="https://www.absolutepath.com/blog.html">x</a>`

Comment: The page loades and navigates to other page, i guess not possible with jsfiddle. Just embed the script and navigate around your page.

Comment: So,where I have to write that code???I cant understand..can you give me any example?

Comment: which one is your link type, full url or short url ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84635/discussion-between-k-c-and-salini).